# What is serving my nginx on the docker?

Tags: nginx, vps, docker

I got the cheapest VPS on Digital Ocean.

I followed [this guide](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/docs/INSTALL-digital-ocean.md), everything works like a charm..

But now I want to serve multiple nameservers on the same ip, so I need to figure it out how this is really working.. I have basically no knowledge about docker..

I read I can log into my docker with

./launcher ssh my_container

I did and it works, I can see the nginx configurations and so on.

Now my question is: how the nginx inside the docker is interacting with the public requests?

I mean, I did find no web server on the local VPS, neither apache or nginx... so is the nginx from the docker responding directly?

Edit: I do have a Docker0 interface

This is my iptable

```
root@droplet0:~# iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 63619 packets, 21M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
77364   33M ACCEPT     tcp  --  !docker0 docker0  anywhere             172.17.0.19          tcp dpt:http
   10   400 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !docker0 docker0  anywhere             172.17.0.19          tcp dpt:ssh
40958   25M ACCEPT     all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
 104K   35M ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 79829 packets, 17M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

I dont understand, the Docker0 has another ip (anyway always in the same subnet), so who is the traffic being forwarded to? Is there a third part between the host and the docker?

Comment: `I have basically no knowledge about dockers.` I hear you put them on one leg at a time.

Comment: [Dockers are a very comfortable brand of slacks](http://us.dockers.com/home/index.jsp) that are popular among white collar workers.  I have no idea what your lack of knowledge about pants has to do with setting up nginx.

Comment: Just to be clear - this isn't the site for you. We generally expect that people who are professionals within system administration to have some skills which you clearly do not.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, guys, I was thinking as they suggested, that is virtual machines, so I meant somehow VMs. @lain, no, you are right, I am not a professional admin, you could do an exception to your expectations and also maybe mentioning which is the site for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing information I can't say for sure, but it sounds very likely that nginx running within Docker is what is serving up the page. I would first suggest you familiarize yourself with Docker: https://www.docker.com/tryit/

Remember that changes to a Docker container are not persistent. You have to save the current state in an image. When you launch a container using the new image, it will have your changes in it. One of the simplest ways to update configs on an image is to use an existing one in a Dockerfile http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/. You could create the configs and web page files as you're used to doing, then use the ADD directive to place them in the correct location in your image. When you launch this new image, nginx will see the configs for these web pages and load them.

Docker networking by default creates an interface called Docker0. It can expose a port on the Docker container to the host's interface, so likely it is exposed on port 80 on your host. The docker container could be using any port on the Docker interface. They can be mapped sort of like a NAT translation with a firewall.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, man, that link is very useful. You are right, I have a Docker0 interface but the forwarding in the iptables looks strange, I inserted it in my answer. Anyway, rather than modifying the docker image, since it was more a test scenario for some forum software, what about instead having my own nginx on the host? Would there be any interference if properly configured?

Comment: It's hard to read the iptables for this, I find it easier to check using the command `docker ps`. Here is an example entry for a running container:
`3242e72ac608        squid_egress:latest   supervisord         7 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        0.0.0.0:3128->3128/tcp   compassionate_rosalind` the first section is the binding on the host (interface and port) and the second is the port on the docker container. Running nginx on the host won't effect Docker, just remember that right now Docker could be using port 80/443 on the host.